# Ampersands within Text strings of PLSQL as datasource for Tableau

Tags: oracle, plsql, tableau-api

I am using a PLSQL query for a datasource (custom Sql Query) Tableau 10.  I am having an issue with tableau recognizing the Set Define Off and Escape on & off- which handles the special characters such as ampersand (&) within the IN statement string of the PLSql.  ie. "SS&MS" or "FT&E" or "Safety & Fire"

I have used Escape on off also without success for Tableau to recognized these terms.

Is there a way to use this PLSql statement containing the ampersands within the strings.

Comment: What do you mean by a PL/SQL Query? SQL has queries, PL/SQL has procedures, functions, packages, blocks, object types etc. Also `set define` and `set escape` are part of SQL\*Plus and not SQL or PL/SQL. Are you using SQL\*Plus? What handling isn’t working?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ampersand with `chr(38)` and then there's nothing to escape.

Instead of:

```
select 'A & B' from dual;
```

Use:

```
select 'A ' || chr(38) || ' B' from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help in escape value conditions

```
select 'A'||'&amp;||'B' from dual;
```

or this way

```
resp:= REPLACE(resp,'&','&'||'amp'||';');
```